# I cannot manipulate/select divs loaded via Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've a simple application, and I decided to use ajax to load levels for simplicity / whatever reason (maybe to learn a bit).

But I'm stuck...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "actions.php",
    get: "GET",
    data: "show_level=" + 1,
    cache: false,
    success: function (views){
        $(".slides_container").append(views);
    }
});
```

The problem is, views appended to my container is not selectable anymore, basically all jquery functions I had stopped working alltogether.

What is happening?

Comment: There's no reason that shouldn't work, provided you're trying to interact with the elements defined by the markup in `views` **after** they've been appended. So within the `success` handler, after the `append` line. If you can create a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org), we could probably help you, but the above is fine (other than one small typo that doesn't matter) -- the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I am pretty sure you want `type: "GET"` not `get: "GET"`

Comment: You have a small error in the above, but it doesn't matter. It should be `type: "GET"`, not `get: "GET"`. It doesn't matter because there is no `get` option, and `"GET"` is the default `type`.

Comment: Are you saying that things like 'click' events are not working on appended element?

Comment: Eventually, you may need to use triggers with `.live()`, for example
`$('a.test').click(function(){` change with `$('a.test').live('click', function(){`. Maybe.

Comment: @ceruleus `.live` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. `.on` should be used

Comment: @DavidBarker Yep, click events don't work. I use: $(".logo").on("click", function(){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bindings like `$(".target-element").click(function(){ do something here});` they are only valid for elements already in the DOM when the binding happens.

You would need to use `$("#element-already-in-dom").on("click", ".target-element", function(){do something here});`

Comment: :) pain to rewrite all selectors :S is there a faster way to do this? like move all into success function of the ajax call?

Comment: Sure you can, but quicker does not necessarily mean better. You will be repeating code potentially multiple times that instead could be done only once.

Comment: This slider for example doesn't work if I don't put it inside success msg. How do I rewrite that in your proposed way?  var unislider = $(".slides_container").dpUniSlider({
  //loop: false,
  draggable: false
 });

Comment: p.s. .slides_container is a valid DOM element, only it's lis come from ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You are a victim of non event bubbling.

When you bind an event to an element you typically do this on window load. If an element is added to the DOM after window load, the event will not be bound to it, despite it meeting all other conditions as laid out by your event handler.

Instead, you must use delegation, this means that events are bound to non changing elements on the page and then bubble up to the correct elements.

```
$('.appended-view').click(function(event) { ... }
```

Will not work

```
$('body').on('click', '.appended-view', function(event) { ... }
```

Will work